# JOLT split flat object into key/value array

Tags: json, jolt

I'd like to split simple flat object into array, so each key/value appear as array element. Example:

**Input**

```json
{ 
   "FIRST_NAME": "John",
   "LAST_NAME": "Doe"
}
```

**Desired output**:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "FIRST_NAME",
    "value": "John"
  },
  {
    "key": "LAST_NAME",
    "value": "Doe"
  }
]
```

Tried various configs but couldn't get anywhere close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine each key-value pair through use of **$** and **@** wildcards respectively within shift transformation spec such as

```json
[
  { 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "[#2].key",
        "@": "[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
 ]
```

where

**[#2]** on the right hand side of the spec represents going up two levels up by traversing one colon(**`:`**) and an opening curly bracket(**`{`**) and grabbing the indices of the arrays for added **key** and **value** nodes respectively as using them along with above mentioned wildcards.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]